# how to make a simple email text sender in android?

Tags: android, http, email

I'm making a simple email post service app in android that will be implemented in my new project.
 how can I perform a simple email sender, that will include the email address and some text to be send to a valid email address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find what you need in this tutorial: [Email sending in Android](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/email-sending-in-android/)